# Why is 050 not equal to 50 in the following snippet?

Tags: c

Why is `050` not equal to `50` in the following snippet?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int x=050,y=50;
    int ans;
    ans= x==y ? x+3 : y+7;
    printf("%d\n",ans);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `050` is considered octal and `50` is considered decimal.

So `x = 050` basically means `x = 40`.

> 6.4.4.1/3
>
> A **decimal constant begins with a nonzero digit** and consists of a
>   sequence of decimal digits. **An octal constant consists of the preﬁx 0**
>   optionally followed by a sequence of the digits 0 through 7 only.

Answer (score 3):

050 is interpreted as octal, with 8 instead of 10 as the number base.

Comment: You probably meant octal.  Octadecimal would be base 18.

Comment: @BabannaDuggani if you think this answer helped you, you should accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

same reason why 0x50 is not the same as 50 or 050

- 50 - base 10
- 0x50 - base 16
- 050 - base 8 (never seen the need to use this, ever)

Comment: Yep - it's mostly historical. C was developed on DEC PDP machines, and they had 8 general registers, and 8 addressing modes. Their instructions included various 3-bit fields for referencing them, so octal was extremely natural. And C was originally designed and used for implementing Unix on PDPs. I think of octal mode as being like a little native accent that C and its derivatives have, that gives away where they were first brought up. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because `050` is an octal constant.

Answer (score 1):

050 is 40 in octal. The 0 turns the number into an octal literal.