# Trouble with XOR of two binary numbers

Tags: c, binary, decimal, xor

I have a list of numbers from 0 to 16 and I want to XOR their binary form with 0110.

I have place the numbers in int j and will go through a loop to reach each of them. The following is my line of code.

```
j2 = j^(binaryToDecimal(0110));
```

However, I am unable to get the results I want. For example 0 XOR 0110 gave me a result of 16 instead of 0110B = 6.
What am I missing here?

Here's my binary to decimal code if needed:

```
long binaryToDecimal(long n) {
int remainder;
    long decimal = 0, i=0;
    while(n != 0) {
        remainder = n%10;
        n = n/10;
        decimal = decimal + (remainder*pow(2,i));
        ++i;
    }
    return decimal;
}
```

Comment: However, when I changed the code to   
    j2 = j^6; 
it worked... What's the difference?

Comment: See Octal representaiton. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782747/why-is-050-not-equal-to-50-in-the-following-snippet/7782755#7782755

Comment: don't use `pow(2, i)`. Replace with `1L << i` instead

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . Including the exact input and output provided, if any.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that when you pass "0110" as an argument then compiler treat it as an octal number i.e. 0110 ==> 72 (decimal).

Instead, pass "110" as in argument. Yo will get the expected result.

Comment: When 72 is passed as an argument then binaryToDecimal calculates its binary equivalent as follows:-

7*2^1+2*2^0
= 14 + 2
= 16

Answer (score 0):

In C any '*number*' that is prefixed with a `0` will be interpreted as octal.

Here are the common numeric prefixes:

- `0b10110` - Specify binary (base 2) with the `0b` prefix - *only supported by some C compilers*
- `026` - Specify octal (base 8) with the `0` prefix
- `22` - Specify decimal (base 10) with '*no*' prefix
- `0x16` - Specify hexadecimal (base 16) with the `0x` prefix

All of the examples above are equal (`22` in decimal / base 10).

By far my preferred approach would be for you to get comfortable with hexadecimal. That would entirely remove your dependency on a function to '*convert binary to x*', as well as any implementation errors in that function.

Try:

```
j2 = j ^ 0x06;
```

Or (if your compiler supports it):

```
j2 = j ^ 0b0110;
```

This is clear, concise and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

As already covered, `0110` is an octal number so `binaryToDecimal(0110)` won't work. You can use similar syntax to express the number you wanted to (as long as you're using a compiler that supports C++14 or better) with `0b0110`. This probably more clearly expresses what you meant compared to `binaryToDecimal(110)`.

With this, your first line would be written as

```
j2 = j^0b0110;
```